# Magento: Deleting existing upsell products when new ones are imported?

Tags: magento, import

I am importing upsell products for my shop. This works without any problems. The only problem that I have is that the import just adds the new ones to the existing ones, no matter what import options I select ("append complex data" or "replace existing complex data").

Is there a way to delete the existing ones completey and only have the new ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) for a better way of importing data, also another way is to first go to the database and run

```
DELETE l.* FROM catalog_product_link as l
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_link_type as lt ON (lt.`link_type_id` = l.`link_type_id`)
WHERE lt.code = "up_sell"
```

assuming you need a quick fix, I would advise against using the DB way unless you know what you are doing. Magento importing is generally buggy.

P.S. thank you  user1856596 for pointing out my typing error.

Comment: That works with one little modification. Its up_sell, not upsell.